# Is there a reverse-map function?

Tags: clojure

In clojure you can map a function to a sequences of values. Is there an inbuilt function to map a single value as parameter to a sequence of functions?

```
(map inc [1 2 3 4])
; -> (2 3 4 5)

(reverse-map [inc dec str] 1)
; -> (2 0 "1")

(reverse-map [str namespace name] :foo/bar/baz)
; -> (":foo/bar/baz" "foo/bar" "baz")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's `juxt` which is a bit similar. It takes a number of functions and returns one that passes its argument(s) to each of the functions and returns a vector of return values. So:

```
> ((apply juxt [inc dec str]) 1)
[2 0 "1"]
```

The main difference is that it creates a vector, which is of course eager (i.e. not lazy.) The original `map` creates a sequence which is lazy.

`juxt` also works on functions that have more than 1 argument:

```
> ((apply juxt [* / -]) 6 2)
[12 3 4]
```

Comment: Apply isn't really necessary though, (juxt * / -) would do as well.

Comment: @NielsK You are right but I left the apply to show how it can be used to "fun-map" sequences of functions, as the asker requested.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if there is one, but it's fairly easy to implement:

```
(def reverse-map (fn [l value] (map #(% value) l)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say use juxt if laziness isn't necessary, especially because of it's composing abilities. However, a straightforward version of your reverse map for polyadic functions that uses map and repeat, which both are lazy, would look like this:

```
(defn reverse-map
  [fcoll & args]
  (map apply fcoll (repeat args)))

=> (reverse-map [inc dec str] 1)
(2 0 "1")
=> (reverse-map [* / -] 6 2)
(12 3 4)
```

Okay, just to throw in an idea, here's a version with the same composability of juxt. And it even seems to [be lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049925/any-merit-to-a-lazy-ish-juxt-function) !

```
(defn lazy-juxt
  [& funs]
  (fn [& args]
    (map apply funs (repeat args))))

=> ((juxt inc dec str) 1)
[2 0 "1"]
=> ((lazy-juxt inc dec str) 1)
(2 0 "1")

=> ((juxt * / -) 6 2)
[12 3 4]
=> ((lazy-juxt * / -) 6 2)
(12 3 4)
```