# Passing one value to two Clojure functions

Tags: clojure

I have one value that I want to pass to two functions. I would expect there to be a clean way to do this in Clojure.

For example, I have a discrete probability distribution, represented as a hashmap. Let's say I want to pass it to both `mean` and `stdev` functions (i.e. my custom mean and standard deviation functions.)

Currently this is what I have:

```
[(mean dist) (stdev dist)]
```

Another way -- not really an improvement -- would be:

```
((fn [x] [(mean x) (stdev x)]) dist)
```

I want to do this more compactly. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`juxt`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/juxt):

```
((juxt mean stdev) dist)
; [82.03M 3.41M]
```

A simpler example with core functions:

```
((juxt inc dec) 2)
; [3 1]
```

A comment: the key advantage in this case isn't really compactness so much as the expressivity of juxtaposing the two functions.

Now that I know that `juxt` was the key, I can find related questions, such as ["Is there a reverse-map?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044254/is-there-a-reverse-map-function). That said, those others were not easily discoverable based on what I knew at the time (10 minutes ago), so I hope this answer will help people discover this sometimes handy function.